# Using Ktor Backend for create Jasperreports

Tags: java, kotlin, jasper-reports, ktor

I got stuck in creating PDF reports. I created a report with Jaspersoft Studio. Now, I want to fill the reports using my Ktor back-end. To activate the function, I'm using postman. I send this  [ /report/1 ] with get to my back-end.

As result, i get this error message:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:  Class not found when loading
> object from file: C:\path\Test.jasper.

To fill the report, I use these functions:

```
fun createReport (userID: String) {
    val id = userID
    JasperCreate(id)
}

fun JasperCreate (userid: String) {
    val parameters = HashMap<String, Any>()
    parameters.put("ID", userid)
    val path = "C://MyFlowDemo/Jasper/Vorlage/Test.jasper"
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/htz", "android", "myflow")
    val jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path, parameters, connection)
    JasperReport(jasperPrint)
}

fun JasperReport (jasperPrint: JasperPrint) {
    val exporter = JRPdfExporter()
    exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint))
    exporter.setExporterOutput(SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("C://MyFlowDemo/Dokument/Test.pdf"))
    val configuration = SimplePdfExporterConfiguration()
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration)
    exporter.exportReport()
}

// JasperReport
get("/report/{p1}") {
    val pUserID = call.parameters["p1"]
    db.createReport(pUserID!!)
    call.respondText { "Report finished" }
}
```

When I create a PDF of Test.jasper with Jaspersoft Studio, I send ID 1 to create a PDF and it works.

Anyone knows, which class is not found or how I find out which class is needed?

Comment: It is better to post the full stack trace

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: [JasperReports: filling a report throws an exception "Class not found when loading object from file"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6649886/876298)